# Is Castle Project's Monorail a viable alternative to ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

One of the reasons I'm askin this is because a lot of the versus topics surrounding these two frameworks are quite old, mostly before 2008, when ASP.NET MVC was still young. As of now, I'm not quite sure how Monorail would fit a beginner like me, but given my circumstances in which I am unable to use VS 2010, and by consequence, ASP.NET MVC, Monorail seems like the best alternative to WebForms.

I know that for the most part, both frameworks achieve the same thing, but what I'm worried about are the little things that I am unaware of as of yet due to my inexperience.

So, the complete question would be, is Monorail a viable to alternative to ASP.NET MVC in a context where I can only use VS 2008?

Answer (score 1):

I may get flamed for this but I would be very leery of starting a MonoRail site at this point.  MonoRail was very nice at one point but at this point the community support around ASP.NET MVC is far greater.  Given you say that you are a beginner I would go with ASP.NET MVC even if it needs to be version 2 for the time being.  There are a huge number of tutorials for you to get started.  Then when you can move to Visual Studio Next and .NET 4+ when the opportunity presents itself.

Once you get a bit of experience if you want to dig into what are no doubt interesting developments in [MonoRail 3](https://github.com/castleproject/MonoRail) you can always do that later.

Comment: I agree, there are lot more articles on ASP.Net MVC now than Monorail (not the case when I started using it 4 years ago). So anyone knows what are the benefits on the new version of Monorail? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218992/what-are-the-benefits-of-castle-monorail-3-over-asp-net-mvc